# Creating a chart with multiple Y axis (3 or more)

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a client that needs to use charts with more than 2 Y axes.

I am already using Component One (C1Chart) chart that has a built in Y2 axis and it's working great.

Does anyone knows of a chart control that can display 3 or more Y axes on a chart?

Comment: I guess you could do that with MSChart by using multiple series

Comment: You can download the Crystal Reports plugin for Visual Studio, you can make reports with it, with all sorts of charts.

Comment: I used [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) on my senior project back in college. It seemed to work out pretty well. The main site hasn't been updated in a while, but you can find some documentation [here](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/), a short tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET), and some samples [here](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html).

Answer (score 11):

[**Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61) contains example of multiple Y axis.
Some pieces of code:

```
    private void checkBoxUseMultipleYAxis_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBoxUseMultipleYAxis.Checked)
        {
            // Set custom chart area position
            Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Position = new ElementPosition(25,10,68,85);
            Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10,0,90,90);

            // Create extra Y axis for second and third series
            CreateYAxis(Chart1, Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"], Chart1.Series["Series2"], 13, 8);
            CreateYAxis(Chart1, Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"], Chart1.Series["Series3"], 22, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set default chart areas
            Chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartArea = "Default";
            Chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartArea = "Default";

            // Remove newly created series and chart areas
            while(Chart1.Series.Count > 3)
            {
                Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(3);
            }
            while(Chart1.ChartAreas.Count > 1)
            {
                Chart1.ChartAreas.RemoveAt(1);
            }

            // Set default chart are position to Auto
            Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Position.Auto = true;
            Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;

        }
    }

public void CreateYAxis(Chart chart, ChartArea area, Series series, float axisOffset, float labelsSize)
    {
        // Create new chart area for original series
        ChartArea areaSeries = chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea_" + series.Name);
        areaSeries.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaSeries.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaSeries.Position.FromRectangleF(area.Position.ToRectangleF());
        areaSeries.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(area.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());
        areaSeries.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaSeries.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;


        series.ChartArea = areaSeries.Name;

        // Create new chart area for axis
        ChartArea areaAxis = chart.ChartAreas.Add("AxisY_" + series.ChartArea);
        areaAxis.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaAxis.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        areaAxis.Position.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF());
        areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());

        // Create a copy of specified series
        Series seriesCopy = chart.Series.Add(series.Name + "_Copy");
        seriesCopy.ChartType = series.ChartType;
        foreach(DataPoint point in series.Points)
        {
            seriesCopy.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, point.YValues[0]);
        }

        // Hide copied series
        seriesCopy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        seriesCopy.Color = Color.Transparent;
        seriesCopy.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        seriesCopy.ChartArea = areaAxis.Name;

        // Disable drid lines & tickmarks
        areaAxis.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
        areaAxis.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        areaAxis.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;
        areaAxis.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font;

        // Adjust area position
        areaAxis.Position.X -= axisOffset;
        areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.X += labelsSize;

    }
```

**Result:**
[image: Multi Y axis off]
[image: Multi Y axis off]

Comment: this data is plotted corresponding to each y axis right?

Comment: @vivek yes, in this particular case we have 3 charts, 3 axises, each chart data corresponding to respective y axis

Comment: The link is not working (anymore). You find a page labelled "Browse code samples" which has (today) 2627 entries, none of them about Windows Forms graph control.

Comment: @fat hi, is it possible to show datetime in x-axis for multiple y. I have tried your code with modification but i am not able to show datetime on x-axis, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try multiple ChartArea's, which allows you to arrange multiple plots in the same chart object.

[You can assign each Series to its own `ChartArea`.](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/documentation/Current/multiple%20chart%20areas.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The [MS Chart control](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) has almost everything you will ever need as far as charting is concerned. Download the sample, run it and go to Chart Features > Axes > Multiple Y axis. I think you will find what you are looking for!