# Multiple Series on a third Y-Axis (Winforms Chart)

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

In my program I have a Winforms chart with multiple Y axes. 
In the implementation I used the example of the highest Answer to this Question:
[C# Winforms - Creating a chart with multiple Y axis (3 or more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805121/c-sharp-winforms-creating-a-chart-with-multiple-y-axis-3-or-more)

For one Series this works fine. But the Problem is that the `CreateYAxis` Method creates two ChartAreas. One for the actual plot and one for the Axis.

So how can I map another series to the third axis, which consists of two ChartAreas?

Comment: If you use your debug , you'll see that there are 5 chart areas associated with 5 series: the original 3 + the 2 extra created by `CreateYAxis`, which, despite the name, is actually creating `transparent` chart areas with their own axes. Very clever hack, actually.

Comment: So, to answer your question: to map another series to the third axis, you have to add this series to the chart area named `AxisY_ChartArea_Series3`, or whatever chart area name is being used in your particular case.

Comment: @jstreet thanks for the answers, but I've tried this. The problem is that the points are then drawn from the added Y-axis rather than from the original Y-axis.

Comment: Well, like i said, you have 5 options. Add your new series to the chart area that gives you the result you're looking for. The original Y-axis is linked to the chart area named `Default`, so try that.

Comment: @jstreet when I link the Serie to the `Default` then the values ​​are drawn from the correct Y-axis, but I would like the unit of the added axis and not the original one.

Comment: You can't have some features from one axis and some features from another. If none of the axis completely satisfies your needs, then you have to create your own and associate your series with it.