# Misalignment of two chart areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, graph

I was trying to overlap two chart areas. They would share the same x values, but Y would have different values and scales.

Here is outcome of my code:

[image: Graph picture]

As you can see red series is not in alignment with green series.I was searching this site for answers, but couldn't find one that worked. Could someone explain me why they don't align?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace TestGraph
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            #region Data

            // Creating first series
            Series s1 = new Series();
            s1.Name = "Values";
            s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            s1.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            s1.Color = Color.Green;
            s1.BorderWidth = 2;

            // Hard Coding test values
            DataPoint[] values =
            {
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 1).ToOADate(), 10),
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 2).ToOADate(), 11),
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 3).ToOADate(), 12),
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 4).ToOADate(), 13),
            };

            // Adding vales to s1
            foreach (DataPoint p in values)
            {
                s1.Points.Add(p);
            }

            // Creating second series
            Series s2 = new Series();
            s2.Name = "Values 2";
            s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            s2.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            s2.Color = Color.Red;
            s2.BorderWidth = 2;

            // Hard Coding test values
            DataPoint[] values2 =
            {
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 1).ToOADate(), 0.1),
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 2).ToOADate(), -0.2),
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 3).ToOADate(), -0.7),
                new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 8, 4).ToOADate(), 13),
            };

            // Adding vales to s2
            foreach (DataPoint p in values2)
            {
                s2.Points.Add(p);
            }

            #endregion
            #region Charts

            // Initializing chart
            Chart mainChart = new Chart();
            ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
            ChartArea area2 = new ChartArea();

            Controls.Add(mainChart);
            mainChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            // Adding areas to mainChart
            mainChart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
            mainChart.ChartAreas.Add(area2);

            // Adding series to areas
            s1.ChartArea = area.Name;
            s2.ChartArea = area2.Name;

            mainChart.Series.Add(s1);
            mainChart.Series.Add(s2);

            // Aligning areas
            // Overlapping area2 with area
            area2.AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
            area2.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All;
            area2.AlignWithChartArea = area.Name;

            // Scale actualization
            area2.RecalculateAxesScale();
            area.RecalculateAxesScale();

            // Defining Y scale
            area2.AxisY.Maximum = 2;
            area2.AxisY.Minimum = -2;

            area2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            // Disabling unnecessary graphics
            area2.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.None;
            area2.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;

            area2.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            area2.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;

            area2.AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
            area2.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

            // Resizing chart back to 100%
            area.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your chart has `AxisX.IsMarginVisible` set to true, the other to false, hence the mismatch.

However, if you are trying to plot overlapping series, why are you not adding them to the same chart area instead of going through all this trouble?

Comment: Because they are on different scale, s1 have values form zero to couple thousands, s2 form minus one to one. When I plot them together s2 becomes just a straight line. Which is bad.

The only way, I found so far is to manualny set scale of second ChartArea:
        `area.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);`
        `area2.Position = new ElementPosition(4.2f, 0, 87.35f, 100);`
But I'm sure there is more elegant solution, as main can work only in couple cases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805121/c-sharp-winforms-creating-a-chart-with-multiple-y-axis-3-or-more

Comment: In any case, commenting out ``area2.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;`` or adding ``area1.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;`` should solve your issue.

Comment: That actually is what I was looking for ([Link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805121/c-sharp-winforms-creating-a-chart-with-multiple-y-axis-3-or-more)). Thank you  :)